What is the "classic" ratio of a crepe?
In "Ratio" M. Ruhlman refers to the basic ratio for crepes to be 1 egg : 1 liquid : ½ flour. Yet most of the recipes I came across, both online and in recipe books, are rather 1 egg : 1.5-3.5 liquid : 1.2-2 flour, e.g.:

Montagné: 1 egg : 3 liquid : 1.5 flour
Pépin: 1 egg : 3 liquid : 1 flour

Is Ruhlman's ratio truly basic and where it was derived from?

It hardly bears mentioning, but historically there was no central organization setting and enforcing standards for crepe batter. Different chefs had different ideas about what an ideal crepe was like and what ingredient ratios would achieve it. So what, to you, constitutes “truly basic”, beyond “what Ruhlman feels is the best ratio to achieve what he thinks of as the ideal crepe”?

I would imagine he either did or relied upon some research as he refers to it as
"the basic crepe recipe", not just a crepe recipe. But in general terms I'm interested whether a popular recipe with this ratio even exists. ATM his choice seems rather random.

It’s the basic crepe recipe in that cookbook. It’s what the variations to it he mentions are variations of: that basic recipe.

The whole point of the entire book Ratio is to get people to stop thinking in terms of finicky recipes, and to start thinking in terms of the relative amounts of ingredients in a recipe.  This provides a framework for experimentation.  Use his recipe to make crepes.  Too eggy?  Reduce the ratio of egg in the recipe (add more liquid to compensate).  Too thin?  Increase the ratio of flour.  Ruhlman is giving you an idea of where to start.  It is up to you to decide what to do with it.

As to where Ruhlman's recipe comes from, he has (had?) a blog.  Prior to the publication of Ratio, a lot of the stuff that is in Ratio, as well as the process of testing recipes and so on, was contained in this blog.  It is reasonable to assume that the crepe recipe he gives is based on his experimentation prior to the publication of the book---the given ratio creates, in the opinion of the author, the "best" version of a crepe.

Sorry, we don't take questions on recipes, and asking for the "classic" recipe for something doesn't make it any more objective. We sometimes allow questions on ratios, but that's a grey area which only works when goal can be clearly described, such as asking which ratio of rice to water would work with a steaming method, assuming that you want to finish with all water cooked off and the rice being neither under- nor overcooked. We certainly don't consider "popular" or "classic" or "historical" to be an answerable criterion.
